# R pivot_wider: Error in Ops.sfc(xi, xj) : operation > not supported

Tags: r, polygon, spatial-statistics, sf, dplyr

I've rerun some data and am now getting this cryptic error message when trying to transfer my `sf` object from long to wide table format.

**Error in Ops.sfc(xi, xj) : operation > not supported**

Does anyone know what this error means?
(It was working before, but I used a slightly different method to create the polygon object and the object was smaller.)

**UPDATE:**
This seems to be a problem with the geometry. The geometry still uses the geometry of the 25m grid, not of the aggregated 250m grid. So dropping the geometry and relinking to the new geometry should do the trick. (I will have to fix this really in the input file, but for the solution I'll stick with the same file.)

---

The data is Corine landcover data for the Helsinki region in polygon format and aggregated to a 250m grid and can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oh49w3JBaXCAHslLMSyIjujAGHrn4b-M/view?usp=sharing) (it's 2.5Gb big) (original data from Syke can be found [here](https://www.syke.fi/fi-FI/Avoin_tieto/Paikkatietoaineistot/Ladattavat_paikkatietoaineistot)):

```
# load packages
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# increase memory
memory.limit(size=56000)

# read data
# geometry of 250m grid is here
# hel.liiteri <- st_read("liiteri.grid.250m.HR.gpkg")
Clc2000.poly.250m <- st_read("Corine.testdata.gpkg", layer="Clc2000")

# change to wide table format
Clc2000.poly.250m.wide <- Clc2000.poly.250m %>%
                            mutate(Clc2000.25m = str_pad(Clc2000.25m, 2, pad = "0")) %>%
                            group_by(GRIDCODE) %>%
                            pivot_wider(names_from = Clc2000.25m, values_from = tot_area,
                                        names_prefix = "Clc_", names_sort = TRUE) %>%
                            na_if(0)
```

I'm running Microsoft R Open version 4.0.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again
```

Long table format:
[image: Table in long format]

Wide table format (example for first 10 rows):
[image]

Comment: The error message happens if R tries to compare to `sfc` spatial objects, eg: `st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1))) > st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)))` but to reproduce this in your context we need all your data (including `sf_liiteri`?). While I wait for a 2.5Gb download, can you make your example reproducible (ie source all data used) and also show the `summary` of the data so we can have a look before the download finishes?

Comment: (I see sf_liiteri is only in the commented out code so maybe not needed)

Comment: If you do it with `names_sort=FALSE` you get *something*. Its *something* with really stupidly long column names that you may need to replace in order to see it. It also works if you drop the geometry first (and then you can still use `names_sort=TRUE`). I worked on a subset of your geopackage with just the first 10 rows for clarity. What output are you expecting for the first ten rows, say?

Comment: I changed to `names_sort=FALSE` and that leads to `Error: Subscript 'i' is a matrix, it must be of type logical.` Will try dropping the geometry next...

Comment: @Spacedman, if you post the following I will accept is as the solution:
`Clc2000.poly.250m <- st_drop_geometry(Clc2000.poly.250m)`
(then code as above)
`Clc2000.poly.250m.wide <- hel.liiteri %>%
  right_join(Clc2000.poly.250m.wide, by="GRIDCODE", keep=FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(1,3,4,5,6,7))`